# Panorama Control not showing data

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am making a Panorama Windows Phone 8 app. This is the first time I have actually used one in an app.

I am having problems showing the data in runtime. Instead I am only seeing a list:

RuntimeOne
RuntimeTwo
RuntimeThree
etc..

I don't have a clue what has happened, it worked the other day. I am going into the SampleData folder and changing LineOne, LineTwo, LineThree, etc but it's not doing anything when I deploy the app to the Windows Phone Emulator.

Comment: First welcome to Stack Overflow. Second congrats on deving for an amazing platform like the windows phone. Now that the formalities are out of the way, please post code when you post questions otherwise the REALLY mean devs come on here and down vote your questions.

Comment: Also, when posting *questions*, "Any help would be grateful" is *not* a question. When you update your question with the [code you have](http://www.sscce.org/) also put in a question, for instance "How would I solve this?" or "What do I need to do to display the data as a foo in the bar?". That way, others will have a much easier time understanding what you want instead of guessing.

Comment: Ok, I will take what you have said onboard and work on that for next time. The reason I never posted any code is because I am at the beginning of making that app, just in design stage. I was trying to understand where the data for the string of text goes. Because in design view it says Design One Design Two, etc... And when I change that in the SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml file and run it. It doesn't show, it just says "RuntimeOne, RuntimeTwo, etc..." down the scrollView!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that there are two different sets of data, and the `DataContext` at runtime is different from design time.

1. The data that you see in design mode ('design one', 'design two') is
   stored in `MainViewModelSampleData.cs`, so changing that doesn't affect
   the runtime experience.
2. The data at runtime is coming from the `LoadData` method in
   `MainViewModel.cs`

At the top of `MainPage.xaml`, you'll see

```
      d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
```

and the "d" namespace here is a mnemonic for 'design'.  If you look at the sample data XAML file, you'll notice it declares a class called `MainViewModel` with a collection of `Items`.

At runtime, `MainViewModel.cs` (specifically the `LoadData` method) adds items one by one to the `Items` property of the `MainViewModel` class, and that class is in turn set to be the *runtime* `DataContext` in the constructor of `MainPage`

The panorama control itself has markup like

```
            <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-22,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
```

so it's expecting to see a collection called `Items` on whatever the current DataContext is, and the fact two different data contexts are in play explains what you're seeing.

The data binding magic is incredibly cool and powerful, but sometimes does leave you scratching your head.